# Consolidation of Software on One Computer

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I have a small business with around 10 or so people that need to use Adobe Acrobat (and other software) every once in a while. So in order to keep costs low, I was considering just installing all the software on one computer, then use Window's `Remote Desktop Connection` to allow my employees to access it.

The main concern was that `Remote Desktop Connection` does not allow simultaneous connections on a non-server installation. I was considering purchasing a server and Windows Server 2012 to allow for simultaneous users, installing the software on the server, creating individual user accounts, and allowing `Remote Desktop Access`.

Do you think I am going about this the right way? Or is there a far easier and more efficient method?

Comment: Actually, there is a hack to allow multiple concurrent RDP connections to a Windows "desktop" OS.  I have no idea how that works with licensing, or the legal status of it, so I'm not going to post a link, but it is a useful thing to have on a small home network, so it might be worth investigating.

Comment: That is most definitely not in compliance with the windows desktop license.

Comment: Please be aware that in many cases this violates the software license terms and conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are going about this the right way.

That said, you need to make sure you're in licence compliance, both with Terminal Server CALs as well as for the Adobe Acrobat software. The TSCALs should be easy enough to purchase and apply, but you will need to examine the Acrobat licensing rules to see if running under Terminal Services is OK under their AUP.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly old doc for Acrobat 9 but likely still valid. http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/wts_9.pdf

*You must have a valid Acrobat software license for every computer that has access to Acrobat software using Windows Terminal Services.*